# Python asynchronous/threads debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code for writing my python application. Inspecting variables and things like setting a watch in the left debugging pane works OK if I write a simple synchronous one-file program.

However, I have code with classes in multiple files, and use various callbacks from other modules. Some which start a new thread.

One of those modules is canopen
I can step thru my code, but when I enter the second line (below)

```
can0 = canopen.Network()
can0.connect(channel='can0', bustype='socketcan')
```

then the call stack changes from:

```
CALL STACK paused on breakpoint
main
<module>
```

to

```
CALL STACK paused on breakpoint
MainThread
Thread#15034.........
```

and simultaneously

- the variables pane clears
- and the watches in my watch window shows:

  `can0: not available`

How can I (setup VS studio code with Python to) inspect/debug my python code with various threads and code in various files?

Regards,
Bas

Answer (score 3):

New debugger is capable of debugging async applications.
Check out how to set it up
[How to update ptvsd used by Visual Studio Code in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774415/how-to-update-ptvsd-used-by-visual-studio-code-in-debug-mode)
And don't forget to add  "subProcess": true, in launch.json

Answer (score 1):

Set the debug to works with Visual Code.

You can see a good article about how you can set the debugger [here](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/debugging/) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), see:

> The setting "stopOnEntry":true will cause the debugger to break at the
>   first line of the python program being debugged. If this is not
>   desired, then change the value from true to false. The default value
>   of this setting is true.