# How to update ptvsd used by Visual Studio Code in debug mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

VS Code continues to use /.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.3.69010/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py while I need 5.0 for some of it's features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/2104 and forcibly opt into the experiment which has gone live to 100% of users by adding the following setting:

```
"python.experiments.optInto": [
        "DebugAdapterFactory - experiment",
        "PtvsdWheels37 - experiment"
    ],
```

Your issue, BTW, suggests your install is timing out trying to download the last copy of the experiments file.